# Django suddenly not working

Tags: python, django, import

My program was working just fine but suddenlty I could'nt use Django at all.
It seems that it has to do with the Library.

```
   from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.apps import apps
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\apps\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .registry import apps      # NOQA
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango19Warning
ImportError: cannot import name 'RemovedInDjango19Warning'
```

This is my manage.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Helato.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I can't import anything anymore from Django.
I have reinstalled Django but nothng happened.
I have also make a back-up afterwards but nothing changed :/
Can someone help me plz ?

Comment: It sounds like you've updated to django 1.9 by mistake and one of your dependencies doesn't support it yet, you should try installing the correct django version

Comment: I am still in 1.8 :/

Answer (score 0):

I have changed manually the lib...
I added

```
class RemovedInDjango110Warning(DeprecationWarning):
    pass
```

It doesn't make any sens to me but it works...